# Finder directory containing latest iCloud Photos

Tags: finder, photos, photo-stream

I often want to included a recent photo in an email, file upload, or other similar context.

I want to select this image via the normal macOS file picker.

I do **not** want to go through the hassle, each time, of exporting the photo from my Mac Photos library or AirDropping it from my iOS device.

I'm fine finding and exporting *older* photos via Photos. But I want the most recent photos easily available in this directory so that I can quickly select them with the macOS file picker.

---

Is there any way I can "mirror" my latest iCloud Photos into a much-simplified Finder directory?

Requirements:

- I want to save this file location in my Finder sidebar, just like I do for my "Downloads" folder, "Screenshots" folder, etc. `~/Pictures/Recent/` or similar.
- The single directory should contain all of my latest photos from the last day or week or so. Or just the latest 100 images. No subdirectories for each image.
- The images should be in common image formats such as `.jpg`, not `.HEIC`.
- I don't want the images to be iCloud "masters", or pick up edits, or delete from iCloud, or anything like that. Just a dumb copy of photos from iCloud.

---

I expect that this will need to be done via a script or regular automated process.

Do any tools exist that provide this functionality?

How can I create such a regularly-updated directory of my recent photos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Photos directly in the standard macOS file selector

[image]

If you don't see the sidebar you can enable it with the dropdown behind the icon on top left

[image]

Comment: Oh thats new to Catalina! nice..

Comment: @ankii It‘s Mojave, and was already available in earlier versions :-)

Comment: I never scrolled past Tags !! I used to export the photos I needed to share..  Plus I thought it was Finder.app, not a file picker.

Comment: This is good, and mostly exactly what I want. I've never noticed that "media" tab before. I wish it was also visible in the Finder sidebar, not just the file picker!

Comment: Although it can be pretty slow, saying "Loading Images..." for 20+ seconds until the images appear.

Comment: @pkamb Have you set "Optimise storage"  for photos ? Also, I won't trust a Finder overlay with multiple Gigs of photos... My system pref -> Desktop hangs often when mistakenly click "Photos" to pick background from. I voted up regardless for highlighting this *new* feature.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use Photosteam, but I believe this may be an option. (The Photos app may need to be running in the background to sync photos.)

1. Navigate to `/Users/[USERNAME]/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary`
2. Right click and select `Show Package Contents`
3. In the `resources` folder, there will be 2 candidate folders containing the images; cloudsharing or streams. The photos will be located in either of them.
4. from there, drag the folder straight into your favorites bar, or alternatively right click and `Make Alias` to easily access the folder again

As for getting it as a Jpg every time, you may consider if you want to save it as JPG from iPhone end. Otherwise you'll need to look into a script to watch the folder, and  convert /or organise. I use [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) to organise files on my mac, but it's a freemium, and there are probably other options.

Comment: will this work / should PhotoStream still be active if iCloud Photos is being used?

Answer (score 0):

## Smart Search Folder.

Naivgate to `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/2020/01` where `01` is the month to search in, set the kind to "Image" and add the smart search to the sidebar using the Save button.

[image]

Comment: This kind of works, and a Smart Search Folder is a good way to consolidate/flatten a complex directory structure into a "simple folder". But I'm seeing mostly `.HEIC` images and do not want to change that setting in iOS / iCloud. It's also hard to sort by date as everything in that smart search seems to be based on recent random caching / iCloud downloads, not the actual recently-taken photos.

Comment: surprisingly my Mac doesnt give a single result when searched by heic. I have set "optimise storage" idk if it matters

Answer (score 0):

Select a photo using the **File Picker > Media > Photos** feature [in the answer above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379788/19829).

Select a photo, *then re-enter the file picker*.

The file picker will open to the source of your previous Finder location. Rather than showing the media widget again, it shows the Finder path source of those images:

```
~/⁨Library⁩/Containers⁩/⁨com.apple.MediaLibraryService⁩/Data⁩/Library⁩/Caches⁩/com.apple.iLifeMediaBrowser.ILPhotosTranscodeCache⁩
```

This `ILPhotosTranscodeCache⁩` seems to be where [the source images for that media picker are stored](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311236/is-there-any-way-to-reliably-get-rid-of-the-caches-in-com-apple-medialibrary-saf). They are transcoded from `.HEIC` to a web safe format such as `.jpg`. It's also a cache, and not related to the masters directory or iCloud Photos database.

This caches folder can be pinned to the Finder sidebar and used instead of the media widget for a faster experience.
[image: com.apple.iLifeMediaBrowser.ILPhotosTranscodeCache⁩]

Answer (score 0):

## How to show all photos from icloud in macos Ventura in 2022

1. Open The `originals` Photo Library Package Folder in Finder
2. Open Up a Search For All Images in the `originals` Folder
3. Save That Search to Your Sidebar

#### Open The `originals` Photo Library Package Folder in Finder

1. Open Finder
2. Click on the Pictures folder in the sidebar
3. Right Click on `Photos Library.photoslibrary`
4. Click "Show Package Contents"
5. enter the `originals` folder

#### Open Up a Search For All Images in the `originals` Folder

1. Type `⌘+F`
2. Where it says `Kind` is `Any` change `Any` to be `Image`
3. You should see all of your images at this point

#### Save That Search to Your Sidebar

1. Click `Save` near the top right of the find menu
2. Make sure `Add to Sidebar` is checked to ensure it gets put in your sidebar

##### If you really only want the latest photos

If you did only want the latest photos then you could modify the search to only include photos from a specified date and later. I suspect that most people viewing this would want to see all of their photos however.